# Apollo client couldNotConvert NSArray to Swift.String in GraphQL

Tags: arrays, json, swift, graphql, apollo-client

I am facing issue while using GraphQL Apollo Client iOS library. The error is look like this,

```
SERVER ERROR : Error at path "getLeadField.0.options)": couldNotConvert(value: <__NSArrayI 0x2817dbae0>(
{
    id = 1;
    optionvalue = "Work Email";
},
{
    id = 2;
    optionvalue = "Personal Email";
},)
, to: Swift.String)
```

Actually when I call method from the apollo client which is look like as below it gives a failure response as above.

```
  Network.shared.apollo.fetch(query: query) { (result) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let graphQLResult):
           //success logic
        case .failure(let error):
           //failure log with error message
        }
  }
```

The `options` key is having a JSONArray from the server side and in other platform like Android and React Front end it is working. Even I have check with different playgrounds of GraphQL everywhere it works. Only In iOS client library (Apollo) it creates a issue.

If anyone have resolve this please help me.

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: It's look like you are trying to get an array object casting it to String. Are you sure that, on Graph server that kind of object is an Array and not a String?

Comment: In schema.json i checked this `options` key have type as `JSON`.  And also in GraphQL Navigation schema it shows `JSON`.

Comment: Maybe this kind of object should be casted as Array and not as String. From error message seems that you are trying to cast it as String.

Comment: First of all i am not doing any casting or something, as for GraphQL query request you need to use graphQL client and their methods for calling a Query to Server for communication. And This `apollo.fetch` method is from client itself. And during that in their library they provide me a log message with this error type and details.

Comment: See this link might it will help you: https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios/issues/36

May be this is a conversion error.

Comment: JSON will accept the `[String: Any]` type of object in apollo. If you're passing the array of object so it will not accept this format and will give this error.